# How to improve vessel segmentation such that parts of blood vessels are not being removed when removing small contours?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-segmentation, retina

Am able to somewhat segment the blood vessels through subtracting blurred image from the green channel image, but several vessels contours are still removed when removing contours under a certain area (noise). I am currently removing any contours under 100 area, but when I move up to 1000, or 500, many of the vessels get broken up.

First, I subtracted a median blurred green channel from the original green channel image. I tried simple cv2.blur, median blur, and bilateral filter, but the results are virtually the same. I don't know if I need to do certain morphological operations, but the overall goal is too make sure that the blood vessel contours are still connected when I remove larger noise contours.

Code:

```
import os 
import numpy as np
import cv2
def vessels(file):
    img = cv2.imread(file)

    #green channel extraction to provide most vessel information
    imgG = img[:,:,1]

    imgblurred = cv2.blur(imgG, (100,100)) 

    f5 = imgG - imgblurred


    ret,f6 = cv2.threshold(f5,15,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)    
    mask = np.ones(f5.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255    
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(f6.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt) <= 100:
            cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 0, -1)            
    im = cv2.bitwise_and(f5, f5, mask=mask)
    ret,fin = cv2.threshold(im,15,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    return fin
```

This is the original:
[image: Original Image]

This is what I can create without removing too much noise:
[image: Lots of Noise]

Little noise:
[image: Little Noise]

But when I do have little noise, some eyes have blood vessels split and get removed halfway:
[image: Problem when Little Noise]

Comment: Did you try to use Canny and HoughLinesP algorithms? You probably can use dilate too.

Comment: I haven't tried HoughLines yet. When I used dilate, it would require a LOT of iterations to connect the vessels, but by doing so, the noise was also magnified. I'll check back what I did with Canny quickly